# Google gRPC - Failed to parse binary descriptor

Tags: php, grpc, google-ads-api, protobuf-c

My code is working fine on `Dev` server but throws Error on `Staging` server, am I missing anything on `Staging`?

`Error: Fatal Error (1): Failed to parse binary descriptor in [../app/Vendor/googleads/google-ads-php/metadata/Google/Ads/GoogleAds/V8/Services/ConversionUploadService.php, line 124]`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused due to the binary file being corrupted. Please, find details on the link below if you encounter similar issues:
https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-php/issues/640

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33868449)